# how to add own coordinates for google map in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have an angualr application where I am using a map to display the coordinates stated on the page. These coordinates are obtained from a different controller on my app.
Now the problem arises when I add coordinates manually in the code such as:

```
 <google-map center={latitude:51.753777,longitude:-1.260361}" zoom="zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
```

But when I add my own latitude and longitude the google map does not display:

```
 <google-map center="{latitude:place.place.lat,longitude:place.place.lng}" zoom="zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
```

There are no errors in the console. 
What could be the problem as I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Shouldn't it be between `{{` and `}}`?

Comment: where would that be?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'm mixing stuff up myself (Twig & Angular).

Comment: That does not work, shows an error